# How to update Link-To-SQL's designer.cs from DBML file?

Tags: c#

I've added to a database's table a field. 
I've updated the dbml file. The field is there.

The link-to-sql's designer file supposed to be updated automaticaly but the field that I've added doesn't appear.

**How to update it in order to use this field in my project ?**

I hope that i'm understandable !

Nicolas

Comment: did you build your project after adding the field/property to dbml file

Comment: Indeed, building makes me some errors that I need to fix before to try it again. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open the .dbml in layout view.
2. Remove the existing mapping
3. Drag your table from server explorer in layout view. This will update your .layout file.
4. Rebuild your project to update the .designer.cs file.